# AngularJS need to click more than 1 time for UI update?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have simple button inside toolbar:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="row" layout-align="space-between left">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/ic_local_airport_24px.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h2>
            <span class="md-title">
                <font>
                    Title
                </font>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <span>
            <!--
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="languageEnglish"
            style='width: 1px !important;
            padding-left: 2px !important;
            padding-right: 2px !important;'>|</md-button>
            -->
            <md-button ng-click='test()' class="md-icon-button">Test</md-button>
        </span>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

When I click the button, the function `test()` fires, but the ripple effect doesn't. I need to click it twice to ripple effect take place.

I also have tab:

```
<md-tabs class="tabs" layout="row" md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" 
    md-align-tabs="bottom" md-stretch-tabs="always" md-no-pagination="true" md-no-ink="false"
    md-swipe-content="true">
    <md-tab label="Home" ng-click="tab1Clicked()">
        <md-tab-label>
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/ic_local_airport_24px.svg"></md-icon>
            <div class="tabsDivider"></div>
        </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Location" ng-click="tab2Clicked()">
        <md-tab-label>
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/ic_local_airport_24px.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

When I click the tab, it fires the function too but the tab UI is not updated. So for example, I am from tab1 clicks tab2, the tab2 background color is not updated although the logic inside the function has been executed. I need to click 2 times upto > 5 times (intermittently, sometimes 1 click also changes the UI).

Why does this happen? How to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide the plunkr url

Comment: This happens mostly on real device. I use AngularJS and AngularJS Material for my mobile app.